# Loop over fsolve Scilab

Tags: for-loop, scilab

Just as a silly example, say that I wish to solve for the following nonlinear equation *x^2 - F(c)=0,* where *c* can take different values between zero and one and *F* is a standard normal CDF. If I wish to solve for one particular value of *c*,  I would use the following code:

```
c = linspace(0,1,100);
L = length(c);
x0 = c;

function Y = eq(x)
Y = x^2 - cdfnor("PQ",x-c(1),0,1)
endfunction

xres = fsolve(x0(1),eq);
```

My question is: Is there a way to solve for the equation for each value of *c* (and not only c(1))? Specifically, if I can use a loop over **fsolve**? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your script like this:

```
c = linspace(0,1,100);
L = length(c);
x0 = c;

function Y = eq(x)
Y = x^2 - cdfnor("PQ",x-c,zeros(c),ones(c))
endfunction

xres = fsolve(x0,eq);
```

Comment: +1. It indeed works for the above "silly" example.  However, it fails to work for a slightly modified equation.  I updated the OP.

Comment: You have to do it sequentially with a loop. Eventually, use the previous solution as starting value.

Comment: However, cdfnor works with a vectorial argument, but there is no interest to call the function in eq() since the arguments do not depend on x (your unknown).

Comment: "You have to do it sequentially with a loop. Eventually, use the previous solution as starting value."  That is exactly what I am asking.  I understand the idea well, the implementation is a challenge.

Comment: "However, cdfnor works with a vectorial argument, but there is no interest to call the function in eq() since the arguments do not depend on x (your unknown)."  Again, this is only a solution for the silly example provided.  Anyways, edited the OP to account for this.

Comment: I udpated the answer.